# Unable to search for a file exploring for Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to integrated with Microsoft Sharepoint files for which i am started working with Microsoft Graph API.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/XXXXdev.sharepoint.com:/sites/test`

It gives me the site id and when i am trying to search for a file with the site id i am getting error

I am able to get the Site ID but unable to search for a file when i am trying with given API.

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')

GET /sites/87fe5e97-7r8f-400f-90a7-ed9306f8uyu7/drive/root/search(q='change')


Response: 400


{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Url specified is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3e63ef7a-ca00-4464-9cfb-1bbfe48d7fee",
            "date": "2019-08-13T10:57:59"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The site id return using "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/XXXXdev.sharepoint.com:/sites/test" like this:

```
xxx.sharepoint.com,7e659ba9-9691-4653-a556-f8a535a6917f,caadc04a-fd57-43e7-9c4b-9cce08050f6b
```

And search for a file with the site id API as below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com,7e659ba9-9691-4653-a556-f8a535a6917f,caadc04a-fd57-43e7-9c4b-9cce08050f6b/drive/root/search(q='change')
```

I suggest you use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test the Graph API.

As a workaround, we can use SharePoint Search REST API to achieve it.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='change IsDocument:"True"'
```

[SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Comment: Thank you that worked. But 1 question instead of searching in a specific site can we search globally ?
ex: i have 3 sites site1, site2,site3 is there any api which can search a given query gloabally in all the sites ?

Comment: It seems not an API to search file in all the sites. As a workaround, you can use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*" to get all sites. Then search file in sites by site id. Or you can use SharePoint search api to achieve it.

Comment: Can you please help me with the SharePoint search api ?

Comment: The SharePoint Search REST API like: https://{server}/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'

Comment: When i try the same in my 3rd party systems i am getting Method failed: (/_api/search/query) with code: 401 - Invalid username/password combo

End Point: https://mydev.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'